# Angular 1.3 - Error instantiating module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and following a tutorial to learn the basics. Below is the code that I have so far. It has a controller and a view

```js
// Code goes here

(function() {
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

  var MainController = function($scope) {
    var person = {
      var firstName = "AAA",
      var lastName = "BBB",
      
    };
    $scope.person = person;
    $scope.message = "Hello";
  }
  
  app.controller("MainController", MainController);
  
}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.19" data-semver="1.3.19" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.19/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <div>First Name: {{person.firstName}} </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

It gives me the below error in console

[image: Error]

Please let me know what I am doing incorrectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in initializing person object:

```
var person = {
  var firstName = "AAA",
  var lastName = "BBB",

};
```

The right way to do that is:

```
var person = {
    firstName: 'AAA',
    lastName: 'BBB'
}
```

Hope, my answer will help you. 
Thanks. : )

Comment: Thank you... I corrected that but the original problem still persists. http://plnkr.co/edit/2OxVp3nLI4QZh6U6LCT0?p=preview

Comment: Your plunkr does not have that change, look here for the fix: http://plnkr.co/edit/hPv2hyVT0z5bqViNCAce?p=preview

Comment: @kayasa You've removed 'var' from object initializing, but you didn't replace = with :, and because of that the error is still there : )